# Rewrite rule to handle url exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an app that serves many sites and I am using Apache mod-rewrite to map the 
url's like this

```
http://site1.net/controller
http://site2.net/controller2/another_view
http://site3.net/
http://special_case.net/
```

maps to:

```
index.php?url=http://site1.net/controller
index.php?url=http://site2.net/controller2/another_view
index.php?url=http://site3.net/
index.php?url=http://special_case.net/hub
```

My rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which handles all the cases except the special last case, where I need to force 
the use of a controller called "hub" when handling a specific domain. I collaborate with others on this project which means I can't do anything about the routing once the index file is called.

Can someone fix my rules so that all the above cases resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current rules don't seem to add the hostname to the url get-parameter. So I added that to to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(special_case\.net)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=http://%1/hub/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=http://%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I could simplify my use case (realised that I do not need to capture the hostname) so didn't use your rules verbatim, but you are obviously a re-write rule master and your answer helped me greatly.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^http://special_case.net index.php?url=http://special_case.net/hub [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The url that the RewriteRule's pattern is applied to never contains the querystring. You'll need to use something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=http://special_case\.net`

Comment: whoops i misunderstood the original question, try the new answer. This should catch the special case.

Comment: Again; The url that the RewriteRule's pattern is applied to never contains the hostname. You need to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(special_case\.net)$` for that. Please test your code before posting.